# Dishwasher heating element knocked through tub

Tags: dishwasher

I recently noticed a leak coming from my dishwasher (Frigidaire
FGID2466QF4A), which appeared to be coming from the heating element nut; it was pretty corroded and had split.  I replaced that nut, but then found that the heating element itself was pushed through the dishwasher tub, so that water continues to leak through.  If I push the element and gasket back up through the tub where they belong, it does seal properly, but eventually something bumps the element and knocks it through again, at which point I essentially just have a hole in the bottom of the dishwasher.

[image: dishwasher heating element]

It looks like there is some damage around the hole that the element sits in - I'm guessing that it's just enough to let the element through.  Would replacing the heating element help at all here - or would the tub itself need to be replaced?  Thanks!

Comment: that depends on the replacement element ... it may have a flange that keeps it from being pushed through

Comment: No the tub would not need to be replaced.  If a replacement element does not have a flange then high temp epoxy or fireplace high temp silicone would seal it.

Comment: I would recommend that you search the internet for `Frigidaire FGID2466QF4A`. I'm sure you'll come up with many places that have schematics and repair parts for you washer (well, a couple at least, depending on how old it is). These will give you a good idea of what the replacement pieces look like and whether they will come with the appropriate hardware to hold this sealed.

Comment: The parts that that I've looked at aren't giving me a good sense for whether a replacement element would have a big enough flange to not go through that hole; but trying a replacement element may be the way to go.  Thanks!

Comment: You haven't really gotten an answer, so if just replacing the element does work for you, please stop back by and write up a self-answer!